# Increase / Decrease Mac Address in Python from String

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, hex

I have a mac address in string form. I am interested in taking the Mac string and increasing / decreasing it by 1 value while keeping the integrity of Hex in Python

Ex: 000000001F

-1: 000000001E
+1: 0000000020

Comment: Those are not valid hex strings in python...

Comment: MAC addresses are 48bit and should be 12 hex digits long (instead of 10)

Answer (score 11):

Parse it, change it, print it!

```
def change_mac(mac, offset)
    return "{:012X}".format(int(mac, 16) + offset)
```